# Symfony2 / Doctrine "app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" brings a ContextErrorException

Tags: date, symfony, get, timezone, default

OS: Ubuntu 13.2
Symfony2 Version: 2.3

I can create my `Test.orm.yml` files and let create my needed `../Bundle/Entity/Test.php`

Now I need the Tables in my (yep existing) MySQL Database so I run the following command:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

The result is an error/warning:

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the
>   system’s timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected the timezone ‘UTC’ for now, but please set date.timezone to
>   select your timezone. in
>   /var/www/html/symfony2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php
>   line 112

I checked my `php.ini` file 
[file: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`]
(that's the file shown when I run `phpinfo()` )

I already added the following line:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"
```

btw. `Symfony/config.php` shows that everything is OK! Not even a info or warning is shown there!

Can anyone help me with that problem? 
Symfony2 is driving me nuts but I have to finish that project!

Thanks in advance!

Alan

Comment: check your php.ini for cli (/etc/php5/cli/php.ini) if the date.timezone settings in correct there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue before, for me it was about different environments. You probably run your app in dev environment, and the doctrine command target the prod one.

First, try to run those commands to see if it's the cause :

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env dev
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env prod
```

Then you should try a **phpinfo()** after switching environment and see if others ***.ini** files are loaded

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas. It works. The "--env dev" options was missing!

Comment: Good for you ! But it should also works in prod environment. When i struggled against this, i've never been able to find the *.ini used in prod on the machine :(

Answer (score 1):

You should also edit the php.ini file under /etc/php. 
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, this configuration is for apache